# MySql: Delete all rows greater than n entries ordered by datetime

Tags: mysql, delete, order-by

Can someone help me with a MySql query to delete all rows greater than n entries ordered by date?

I.e. say I have 1200 rows of data with a timestamp column. I need to order it by date and preserve rows only up to the first 200.

If I have only 199 rows of data, then I need to preserve them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will keep the first 200 rows (and possibly a few more, with identical timestamps):

```
DELETE t
FROM 
    tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT timestampColumn AS ts
      FROM tableX
      ORDER BY ts ASC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 199
    ) tlimit
    ON t.timestampColumn > tlimit.ts
```

---

Additional question: Keep the first 200 rows for every user (by the `uid` column):

```
DELETE tt
FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT uid             --- these 3 lines can be replaced
        FROM tableX                     --- with:   UserTable AS du
      ) AS du                           --- a table that you probably have
  JOIN
      tableX AS tt
    ON  tt.uid = du.uid
    AND tt.timestampColumn >
        ( SELECT timestampColumn AS ts
          FROM tableX
          WHERE uid = du.uid 
          ORDER BY ts ASC
          LIMIT 1 OFFSET 199
        )
```

A `(uid, timestampColumn)` will be useful with a big table.

Comment: This looks awesome. What if I don’t have 200 entries?

Comment: Then the subquery will return 0 rows and the join will be void and thus no rows at all will be deleted. Note that this will keep the 200 oldest rows. If you want to keep the 200 newest, you'll have to change `ASC` to `DESC` and `>` to `<`.

Comment: Which one do you think will be faster?  Your’s or @Ladadadada’s?

Comment: Perhaps you can test with your data and tell us? There is not going to be much difference, I think.

Comment: If I had to do this for all users how should I change the query? I.e. each row has a uid column and I need to delete entries greater than 200 for each user.

Comment: Oh, that would be a problem, tagged with [greatest-n-per-row].

Answer (score 2):

If you have an AUTOINCREMENT primary key, and we can assume that you don't update the timestamp, then this should work and be reasonably fast:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id > 
  ( SELECT max(id) FROM 
    ( SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 200 )
  AS table) ;
```

Given the assumptions above, ordering by `id` rather than `date` would give exactly the same results.  I have also assumed you want to delete anything older than the newest 200 so the `ORDER BY` is `DESC`.

Comment: If I had to do this for all users how should I change the query? I.e. each row has a uid column and I need to delete entries greater than 200 for each user.

Comment: I don't think I can figure out a way to do that in a single SQL query (although it probably **is** possible.)  I would just do a `GROUP BY uid` query to find which users have more than 200 notifications and then do a loop in whatever language you are using to delete all but the most recent 200 for those users.

Comment: The problem with the programming language approach is that I will potentially end up iterating millions of users.